# Showing and Hiding Userforms - Out of Stack Error

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a data driven tool in Excel which has 5 multi-page userforms. Each form contains a number of datafields (250+ across all forms). 13 controls make up each field. So they are quite large.

The system allows a user to open a comments form for each field by clicking a "Show Comments" button. It is connected up using class-based events, using the following code:

```
Private Sub mShowGroup_Click()
    Dim fm As formCommentDisplay 'the form to be shown

    'Snip not relevant code

    HideDataEntry 
    fm.Show
    ShowDataEntry
End Sub
```

The HideDataEntry sub hides the main data entry form so that only the comment form is visible. This is required as the user can display a print version of the comments using printscreen - if the form isn't hidden the user can't close the print screen.

The issue is that the stack is overflowing if the user opens multiple comment forms. The reason is the ShowDataEntry sub.

```
Sub ShowDataentry()
    Dim fForm as Variant

    For each fForm in UserForms
        fForm.Show
    Next fForm
End Sub
```

The code shows the appropriate data entry form, but as the form is Modal it will stay in the stack. Then the next time a comment form is shown the stack will increase, and increase, until Out of Stack Error.

I'm struggling to think of a way to get around this. Due to the sheer number of controls, I don't want to have to have event code for each control. This is why the event code is in a class, and triggered through collections of objects. One thought I had was hiding the form, and then when the code finished using an event trigger in the form to reshow the form - but I don't think that's possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: How you tried running with setting `ShowModal = False`

Comment: I need the form to be modal

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the call for ShowDataEntry to where the form is originally called.

I check if any forms are still loaded and assume I want to show them. Since this is in the same loop that loads the form the stack is effectively reset to the state when the form was originally opened.